# How can I lock a file in android?

Tags: android, file

So the scenario of my problem is in my application I am fetching some file from the internet then I put them in internal storage then when user wants to access these file User can access them through my application.

I did all the thing but I want to provide some security in my application So what I want is?

> 1. User can see my file only in my application. User unable to access them from the file manager. Don't tell me the solution to put dot
>      before file name or folder name I did that the problem with this
>      solution is when I access them by putting dot before file name the
>      file are again visible .
> 2. I also want that when the user open my file ,just like a pdf in pdf reader He/She restricted to save or download them through pdf
>      reader or another application.

Any Kind of help is appreciated by me.

Comment: Use encrypted data to store and decrypt it while read

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042398/lock-file-for-writing-in-android

Comment: Is it complete solution of the problem ? If user is smart he can search my file directly from storage by knowing file size from my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt that file so user won't be able to access them. here is the encryption method which works for me.

```
public void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Here you read your file.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Path Of your file");
    // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Path Of your file");

   // Length is 16 byte
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    // Create cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    // Wrap the output stream
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    // Write bytes
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    // Flush and close streams.
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Here is the method for decryption of particular file.

```
 public void decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Path Of your file");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Path Of your file");
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
int b;
byte[] d = new byte[8];
while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
    fos.write(d, 0, b);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
cis.close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can encrypt your files with an encryption algorithm and save them with your custom file extension then you can make an intent filter for opening them from File Manager and for more security i prefer the JNI For whole Encryption system .

Comment: Just suppose I encrypt the file but user get the file size of my file through my application . If he is smart he can do some search and find the file.